# Dynamic ckeditor toolbar

Tags: dynamic, ckeditor, config, toolbox

I want to set ckeditor tool bar based on the user type and some condition.

Partialy I done as below:

```
switch(UserMode)
{
    case "1":
        config.toolbar_MyTool = [
            ['Find', 'SelectAll'], ['Anchor'], ['Maximize']
        ];
        break;
    case "2":
        config.toolbar_MyTool = [
            ['Find'], ['Anchor'], ['Maximize']
        ];
        break;
}
```

Code goes long based on the usermode
so I want to create a array and just I want to assign the toolbar
like as below:

```
config.toolbar_MyTool = myToolArray;
```

Also I want to check own post or other person post. If it is own post I want to add some tools additionally.

Comment: can you plz tell me how to you got UserMode config.js of ckeditor

Comment: @Archana its my local variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would start by defining your different toolbars in the **config.js**

```
config.toolbar_MyToolUserMode1 = [
        ['Find', 'SelectAll'], ['Anchor'], ['Maximize']
    ];

config.toolbar_MyToolUserMode2 = [
        ['Find'], ['Anchor'], ['Maximize']
    ];
```

Those toolbar-definitions can then be used later **in your page**, but be aware that as soon as you create an instance of CKEditor, the toolbar layout CAN NOT be changed:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = "MyToolUserMode1";
var instance = CKEDITOR.appendTo(parentElement);
```

**Solution 1:**

You would have to create a new instance to change the toolbar dynamically:

```
switch(UserMode)
{
case "1":
    if (instance) instance.destroy();
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = "MyToolUserMode1";
    instance = CKEDITOR.appendTo(parentElement);
    break;
case "2":
    if (instance) instance.destroy();
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = "MyToolUserMode2";
    instance = CKEDITOR.appendTo(parentElement);
    break;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

However, if you are happy with showing the full toolbar also in usermode 2 and greying the SelectAll-Button, then the following could be your solution:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = "MyToolUserMode1";
var instance = CKEDITOR.appendTo(parentElement);

switch(UserMode)
{
case "1":
    instance.getCommand('selectAll').enable();
    break;
case "2":
    instance.getCommand('selectAll').disable();
    break;
}
```

[EDIT feb 15]

**Solution 3:**

According to your comment -> how to dynamically construct with array.push

**No configuration needed in config.js**

```
    // your code
    var myToolbarSection1 = new Array();
    myToolbarSection1.push('Bold');
    myToolbarSection1.push('Italic');

    // attaching this section to toolbar
    var myToolbar = new Array();
    myToolbar.push(myToolbarSection1);

    // setting the toolbar
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Dynamic = myToolbar;
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = 'Dynamic';

    var instance = CKEDITOR.appendTo('myDIVID');
```

Comment: but i need like follow toolbarArray.push('Find'); toolbarArray.push('selectAll'); config.toolbar=toolbarArray; is it possible?

Comment: @RGA added solution 3 according to your question